# Connectors don't show in Altium xsignal wizard in Altium 22

Tags: high-speed, altium

I am trying to create an xsignal link between processor and a connector to measure the timing (because there are resistors on some of the lines). I don't see the connector in the list (J3, the rest are U designators), but I do see a USB connector in the list so I'd imagine that there is some way to get connectors into the xsignal list.

I'm thinking it might be the designator. Is there some trick to get designators to show up on the list?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The text box at the top allows you to filter the component list. In your screenshot, it is set to **U**, so some of your components may not be shown. Make the text box empty to remove the filter and all components will be shown.
Also note the "Min Pin Count" control (top right).
[image: Text box for component filter]